# Get Exact URL in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

Hi I have a jsp page which is loading after executing action class and returning to view.
My url is 
`http://localhost/search.do?operation=searchData&place=Bangalore`
and in the jsp page I need to use this complete url and append some more parameters to the url and send a request.
My question is how do i get the exact url in jsp as it is there in address bar????
I used the following ways but those are not giving me what I expected

```
<%=request.getRequestURL() %>
<%=request.getRequestURI() %>
<%=request.getServletPath() %>
```

These gives me the following

```
http://localhost/jsp/gridSearch.jsp
 /jsp/gridSearch.jsp
 /jsp/gridSearch.jsp
```

Respectively.
Is there any way to get the exact address as it is there in address bar?
like `http://localhost/search.do?operation=searchData&place=Bangalore`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single method that returns everything but something along the lines of the following should work.

```
<%=request.getRequestURL().append(request.getQueryString() == null ? "" : "?" +  request.getQueryString())%>
```